# How to get new array from old array in react native?

Tags: javascript, arrays, react-native, filter, grouping

**React Native** // I have one array like this. How can get new array from this old array that i neet to use it?

```
data = [
    { id: 1, name: 'Mike Mii', city: 'philps', state: 'New York'},
    { id: 2, name: 'Steve Jav', city: 'Square', state: 'Chicago'},
    { id: 3, name: 'Jhonny', city: 'market', state: 'New York'},
    { id: 4, name: 'philps', city: 'booket', state: 'Texas'},
    { id: 5, name: 'smith', city: 'brookfield', state: 'Florida'},
    { id: 6, name: 'Broom', city: 'old street', state: 'Florida'},
  ];
```

I want to get new array that have array in array like this. field `state` are the same should show only one.

```
new_data = [
    {
      id: 1, 
      state: 'New York',
      people: [ 
        {
          id: 1,
          name: 'Mike Mii',
          city: 'philps',
        },
        {
          id: 2,
          name: 'Jhonny',
          city: 'market',
        }
      ]
    },
    {
      id: 2, 
      state: 'Florida',
      people: [ 
        {
          id: 1,
          name: 'smith',
          city: 'brookfield',
        },
        {
          id: 2,
          name: 'Broom',
          city: 'old street',
        }
      ]
    },
    {
      id: 3, 
      state: 'Chicago',
      people: [ 
        {
          id: 1,
          name: 'Steve Jav',
          city: 'Square',
        }
      ]
    },
    {
      id: 4, 
      state: 'Texas',
      people: [ 
        {
          id: 1,
          name: 'philps',
          city: 'booket',
        }
      ]
    }
  ];
```

Answer (score 0):

this should do.

```js
const data = [
    { id: 1, name: 'Mike Mii', city: 'philps', state: 'New York' },
    { id: 2, name: 'Steve Jav', city: 'Square', state: 'Chicago' },
    { id: 3, name: 'Jhonny', city: 'market', state: 'New York' },
    { id: 4, name: 'philps', city: 'booket', state: 'Texas' },
    { id: 5, name: 'smith', city: 'brookfield', state: 'Florida' },
    { id: 6, name: 'Broom', city: 'old street', state: 'Florida' },
];

const result = data.reduce((p, c) => {
    const found = p.findIndex(p => p.state === c.state);
    if (found !== -1) {
        delete c.state;
        p[found].people.push(c);
    } else {
        p.push({
            id: p.length + 1,
            state: c.state,
            people: [{
                id: c.id,
                name: c.name,
                city: c.city
            }]
        })
    }

    return p
}, []);

console.log(result);
```